# Open-source code for computing response functions

Tags: particle-physics, condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

Summing Feynman diagrams to compute the response functions of a microscopic model is common in many areas of physics. While conceptually straightforward, the task can be computationally intensive. Therefore, it is desirable to have a set of code that is optimized for speed.

Is such a set of code available publicly?

Comment: Do you know about https://www.hepforge.org/projects? There may be something there. In general, which of the available tools will work for you will depend on your application. It might also be hard to get effective support from the developer of a high energy physics tool for a condensed matter application... Finally, if you want it done right and with max. efficiency for your problem, you may have to develop it yourself.

Comment: @CuriousOne, thanks, the hepforge projects look invaluable. It would be great if something similar exists for the condensed matter community too.

Comment: Unfortunately I only know a few of the hep tools (and not even the ones you are looking for). Hopefully someone else can give a better recommendation. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a library/program; see [this Meta.Physics post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5603).